# need to get f2py working, but don't know any fortran

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I want to use function OPAC from this source code:
http://opalopacity.llnl.gov/codes/xztrin21.f

i don't uderstand the code very well, I just want to use it as Python module. I run the following:

```
f2py -c xztrin21.f -m opal_opacity
```

but I always get this error:

```
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1819:71: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘!’ token
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c: In function ‘f2py_init_cst’:
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1828:35: error: ‘f2py_setup_cst’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1828:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1819:71: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘!’ token
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c: In function ‘f2py_init_cst’:
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1828:35: error: ‘f2py_setup_cst’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c:1828:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
error: Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.c -o /tmp/tmpWe2VM7/tmp/tmpWe2VM7/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/opal_opacitymodule.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I don't think there's really anything wrong with the code. I believe others got it working alright, so I guess I must have a wrong Fortran complier or something. I'm not sure what to do about it though.

Any help apprecitated

edit:
if I try to compile the code with gfortran I get following:

```
xztrin21.f:1025.72:

      IF (H.EQ.0.) PAUSE 'Bad XA input.'                                
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by creating a signature file first. I ran command

```
f2py -h opal.pyf -m opal xztrin21.f
```

and than

```
f2py -c add.pyf add.f95
```

and it works fine now. I used this tutorial:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this doesn't look like a problem with the Fortran code you linked.

Your actual errors are all found `In function ‘f2py_init_cst’`:

- `:1828:35: error: ‘f2py_setup_cst’ undeclared (first use in this function)`
- `:1819:71: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘!’ token`

Judging by the name, this suggests an issue with the python package `f2py`.
The syntax of the above means that the compiler found errors on `line: 1828, column:35` and `line:1819, column:71` in the `f2py` code.

- I would suggest you check the documentation on `f2py` website and ensure that you are compiling it correctly
- As a test, [work through the examples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html#the-quick-and-smart-way) shown in the `f2py` docs and ensure you can compile them

Comment: i ran the first example without any trouble. might be problem with the compiler afterall. see my edit

Comment: or do I need to have main() function somewhere in the code?

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with your compiler, it must be the way in which you are calling it. Just read through the docs carefully on `f2py`. Furthermore, the second issue you are having is because you are compiling a `SUBROUTINE` with no `PROGRAM`. It is looking for a `PROGRAM` and `END PROGRAM` but I'm guessing you don't have one. So it fails to find `main` because you have no program to compile! See [here](http://www.see.ed.ac.uk/~jwp/pse2/modelling/fortran/simple.html) on how to write a simple `Fortran` program and it should find `main` that way.

Comment: I suggest you call the program from within some basic `Fortran` code first before interfacing it with python

Comment: i got it working now with this tutorial
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html
see my own answer. thank you for your effort alex

Answer (score 0):

```
f2py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 -m modulename filename.f95
```

This command should work.

http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/docs/course-notes/unixcourses/pythonfortran/files/f2py.pdf

This is a very simple document that addresses how to use fortran module in python. This was very helpful to me.

Comment: Also before using f2py. You need to make sure that you have defined the "intent" of the variables correctly. whether its intent(in)or intent(out). If this is not done in the fortran code by default. You can use
"!f2py intent(in) var_name" This would be considered as a comment in fortran code but would be picked up by f2py.